# How to determine the index of the line a keyword of my language belongs to in the Eclipse editor?

Tags: xtext, xtend

I'm using Xtext to design an image building language. For that purpose, the index of the line in which a token is found in the Eclipse editor matters.
Is there a way to find out this line index in the Xtend code of my code generator? I'm using Xtext/Xtend 2.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the information is available though the node model.

you can use `org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.util.NodeModelUtils.getNode(EObject)` to obtain the node of an `EObject`.
`org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.INode.getOffset()` to get an offset.
`org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.util.NodeModelUtils.getLineAndColumn(INode, int)` to get the line information.

you may also have a look at `ILocationInFileProvider` and `ITextRegionWithLineInformation`